# Why styles don't apply to xml inside princexml

Tags: xml, xslt, princexml

I have some XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./example.xsl"?>
<article>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <author>Some Author</author>
</article>
```

and XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <h1>
      <xsl:value-of select="//title"/>
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <xsl:value-of select="//author"/>
    </h2>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I am running this on the browser I have this:
[image]

But I need to generate PDF from this XML, therefore I should use `princexml`, when I am running  `prince ./examples/example.xml` generate pdf with this content:
[image]
Why styles does not apply to xml inside `princexml`?

Comment: H1 & H2 supported in fo?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xslfo2app/index.html#h1-thru-h6

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the display in the browser and in the prince should not match? When I selected the `princexml`, I counted on the fact that it would display what is on the page in the browser and plus print styles that the `princexml` can process

Comment: When I am trying to run `prince ./examples/example.html` `h1` and other `html` tags look as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prince does not support XSL, it supports CSS. Please use an XSLT processor to convert the XML first, then pass the result to Prince.